# SharePoint REST API does not return all the fields from SharePoint Picture Library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I have SharePoint 2013 Picture Library. I am using below `REST API` to access my library.

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + listName + "')/files" + filter
```

But it does not return all the fields of this Picture Library.

I need to fetch `Description` and `ServerRelativeUrl`.

But the `Description` field is missing in the response.

Please refer below REST API response that I am getting ::

[image]

please suggest me if anyone have any idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + listName + "')/files" + filter&$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

You need to add `ListItemAllFields` in the REST endpoint

Comment: Thanks a lot Gautam for your quick response. Appending '$expand=ListItemAllFields' to the URL worked for me.